# Dropdown: How to set a default selection

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi I am trying to set a default selection on my dropdown but I believe angular is preventing this. Here is the code I am using:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="timePeriod" data-ng-change="TimePeriodChanged()">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">Daily</option>
     <option value="1">Weekly</option>
</select>
```

When I remove the angularJS tags it works but when angularJS tags are there it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you need to default the value of `timePeriod`

```
$scope.timePeriod = 0; // or 1 depending on what you want the default to be.
```

See the example in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgnJSxqE7YT9Bwv57odz?p=preview)

**Updated:** new [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgnJSxqE7YT9Bwv57odz?p=preview) to show another option:

This will allow you to create an array of time periods in your controller and bind it to hte options in the select and default your value to the first one in the array.

In your controller:

```
$scope.timePeriods = [{id: 0, name:'Daily'}, {id: 1, name: 'Weekly'}];
$scope.timePeriodOption2 = $scope.timePeriods[0];
```

And in your markup:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-ng-model="timePeriodOption2" 
    data-ng-change="TimePeriodChanged()" 
    ng-options="t.name for t in timePeriods track by t.id"></select>
```